# Netbeans Code Completion

Tags: netbeans

Is there any netbeans trick that would do like Sublime text that if you just type div.header-class then it will then just automatically formulate `

```
<div class=header-class"></div>
```

How to do that trick? or is it possible?

Comment: This feature is called 'Code Snippets'. https://www.google.com/search?q=sublime%20snippets&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably through a plugin known as [Emmet](http://emmet.io/).

NetBeans has [a plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48315/emmet) for it too.  The plugin page indicates that it's for older versions, but the comments are reporting success with version 8.1.  Incidentally, it doesn't show up in the plugin manager from NetBeans on Windows for me, but the [GitHub page](https://github.com/emmetio/netbeans) looks active though.

The Emmet [download page](http://emmet.io/download/) points to this repo.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans you have [`Code templates`](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates.html):

> Code templates are prewritten snippets of code provided by NetBeans IDE. You can paste a snippet into your code by using code completion or the template's abbreviation followed by the Tab key.

Following the tutorial linked you can define your own code template to meet your requirements.